# How can I add custom image to typeahead drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

The drop-down is populated from a remote table which also contains the url of the corresponding image. I am using typeahead 0.9.3. What method can be used to add custom images to the autocomplete?

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', 'root', '*****');

$query ='%'.$_GET['query'].'%';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT event FROM events WHERE event LIKE :query");

$stmt->bindParam(':query', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$results = array();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `template` option to your typeahead initialization. 
You template must use hogan as rendering engine to replace the img source for your remote value.

For example, if you remote query returns a JSON object like this:

```
{"value":"test","img":"url to image"}
```

You must to configure typeahead this way:

```
$input.typeahead({
   name: "autocomplete",
   template: "{{value}}<img src='{{img}}'/>",
   engine: Hogan,
   remote: "/remoteUrlToFill?q=%QUERY"
});
```

I've created a straightforward jsfiddle to test this (see at the end of the javascript area to see the custom code):

http://jsfiddle.net/vfportero/KJFje/1/

Instead of remote source I used a local json object but this mustn't be a problem if your remote response looks like the local object

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. What is the {{value}} a placeholder for?

I'll try this out and let you know!

Comment: Sorry, my example JSON isn't correct. {{value}} renders the "value" in the response json object.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. My drop down is only showing undefined which means that there is a problem with my php query. I am not sure how to modify the exisitng one to get the correct output. Could you have a look?

Comment: Let's say I need to select 'ID' from the events table as well. How to modify the $results that is bring returned?

I added the code to question to make it readable.

Comment: mmm, you need the 'ID' and 'event' values in your typeahead results no? Is this values exists in your JSON response object you can render it in your hogan template using the correct placeholder

Comment: How do I ensure that the JSON is rendered correctly. I have tried that but it doesn't display anything in the dropdown. 

How should I change the population of results?

Comment: Hi, i've created a example in jsfiddle. Please, check it out in my answer. You can test with the text "google" & "twitter"

Comment: I tried your example and that is exactly what I want. My JSON is being returned correctly but the drop down is blank.

Thank you for all the effort.

Comment: :( You can try to add the "filter" callback option to your remote configuration and try to debug or update to current version and use Bloodhound.